# How to use anchor tag on iframe?

Tags: html, iframe

I am new to HTML and i don't know JavaScript.I want embed a badge to my website using iframe tag `<iframe src="URL" width="500" height="50" frameborder='0' align='middle'>` and when some one clicks on it,i want to open a website in a new tab.
 I tried adding **`<a>`** tag around frame tag but **only the borders** of frame are hyper linked not the badge . how do I link the badge embedded in an frame to a new site?

Comment: Code inlined into paragraph is not a great effort in asking a question. Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working Answer :

NOTE : Onclick will take you to go to google.com in new tab. This You can click only once. The Listener resets on refreshing the main page again.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
focus();
var listener = window.addEventListener('blur', function() {
    if (document.activeElement === document.getElementById('myFrame')) {
       var win = window.open('https://www.google.com', '_blank');
        win.focus();
    }
    window.removeEventListener('blur', listener);
});

</script>

<iframe id="myFrame" src="https://www.codewars.com/users/balajis/badges/large" width="500" height="50"  align='middle' frameborder='0'">
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your Badge as a image.

```
<a href="NEW_SITE_URL" target="_blank">
  <img width="220" height="250" border="0" align="center"  src="BADGE_URL"/>
</a>
```

Comment: it is not an image

Comment: What is it then ? can you be specific ?